# Zoho crm API sometimes returns error

Tags: api, crm, zoho

I'm trying to searchRecord using the Zoho CRM API and I sometimes get the following error:

> Array ( [response] => Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => Unable
>   to process your request. Please verify whether you have entered proper
>   method name,parameter and parameter values. [code] => 4600 ) [uri] =>
>   /crm/private/json/Contacts/searchRecords ) )

My problem is that sometimes everything works fine and sometimes I get this error

```
define("TARGETURL", "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Contacts/searchRecords");
$parameter = array(
            'scope' => 'crmapi',
            'authtoken' => AUTHTOKEN,
            'selectColumns' => 'All',
            'criteria' => '(Account Name:'.$accountName.')',
            'fromIndex' => $fromIndex,
            'toIndex' => $toIndex
            );
$ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, TARGETURL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameter);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try search field with double quotation mark, following is script to search email from lead module.

```
     $xmlData = "(Email:$email)";
         $ch = curl_init('https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/searchRecords');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); //standard i/o streams
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Turn off the server and peer verification
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set to return data to string ($response)
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //Regular post

         $authtoken = "********************************";
         $query = "authtoken=" . $authtoken . "&scope=crmapi&criteria=" . $xmlData;

         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query); // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
         $response = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
```